# No suitable driver found for jdbc.mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm a student doing a course in Java and I've been stumped by an error I cannot resolve.

The error as mentioned above is

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc.mysql
```

I've imported the Library and specified it in code, I've also tried numerous solutions posted by users on stackoverflow and yet, nothing.  If anyone has any further suggestions help would be greatly appreciated

My code

(I had to change my Xampp server conf file to listen to port 8080 because 80 was occupied by PID4 "System")

```
public class DBConnect {

  String DB_URL = "jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/phpmyadmin/BCStationary?";

  public DBConnect() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "");
      System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println("Conn error ");
      Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the correct jar file to your project?

Comment: there is no need to call `registerDriver()` or `Class.forName()` (and if there was only **one** would be required)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your URL, which is not following the standard protocol.

Use:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/..."
```

(note the colon instead of the dot between `jdbc` and `mysql`).

**Notes**

- You don't need the question mark at the end if you're not using parameters. 
  But you will need either properties or GET-like parameters if your database requires authentication, etc.
- I'm not sure about the `phpmyadmin` part. I suspect you'll need to remove that and point to your database name directly.
- You don't need to explicitly register the driver. In Java <= 6, you will still need the reflective `Class.forName` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");` should come before `DriveManager.registerDriver`.

`DriveManager.registerDriver` doesn't need to be use either.

You can simply your method by:

```
  public DBConnect() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
      //Call to .newInstance() is a work around for some
      // broken java instances.
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "");
      System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println("Conn error ");
      Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
```

If you are using the latest mysql drivers (mysql-connector 8.0) the class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: Why is that call to `newInstance()` in your code? In fact do you even need to call `Class.forName()` for either of those JDBC drivers? Aren't they both Type 4 drivers?

Comment: The mysql documentation state that `Class.forName` still needs to be called otherwise the exception will be thrown. The call to newInstance() is a work around for some broken java instances. depends on what version the OP is running.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306  /dbname","UserName","Password");

     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    please add mysql-3.0.5-connector jar  file
   there is not required to registerDriver and other
```